# Pyspark inner join returning unexpected results

Tags: pyspark

Joining two tables with the exact same number of rows and and identical keys yields a null dataframe.

Hi, was wondering if I could get help on an unexpected bug while running inner join on 2 tables. I'm fairly new to pyspark and this was ran on a Databricks spark cluster.

Firstly, two Pyspark tables are loaded in as such and filtered for only a single day's applications.

```
table_1 = spark.table(table_1_path)
table_2 = spark.table(table_2_path)
table_1 = table_1.filter(F.col('application_date') == '2023-10-09') # should return 473 rows
table_2 = table_2.filter(F.col('application_date') == '2023-10-09') # should return 473 rows
```

Next, before joining `table_1` and `table_2` on a common key column: `application_id`, I filtered `table_2` for the columns of interest.

```
cols_of_interest = ['application_id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3']
table_2 = table_2.select(*cols_of_interest)
```

And last, executing inner join on both tables. This should yield a table of 473 rows as both tables after filtering share the exact same list of `application_id`.

```
print(table_1.join(table_2, on='application_id', how='inner').count()) # yields 0 instead of 473
```

Interestingly, doing the following results in the desired value of 473

```
print(table_1.join(table_2.select('*'), on='application_id', how='inner').count()) # yields 473
print(table_1.select('*')join(table_2, on='application_id', how='inner').count()) # yields 473
print(table_1.join(table_2, on=table_1['application_id']==table_2['application_id'], how='inner').count()) # yields 473
```

even swapping the operations of table_2 to select `cols_of_interest` first followed by filtering on `application_date` column(which should not be present in this case) works and returns 473. Doing a left join instead of inner(no null values on the left joined columns), or converting both tables to pandas and doing a merge yields the desired result as well.